# Spark shuffle error org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)

Tags: apache-spark

I have a job which processes large volumes of data. This job frequently runs without any error but occasionally it throws this error. I am using Kyro Serializer.

I am running Spark 1.2.0 with yarn cluster.

Full stacktrace here:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$.org$apache$spark$shuffle$hash$BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$$unpackBlock$1(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$$anonfun$3.apply(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$$anonfun$3.apply(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:83)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedValuesRDD.compute(MappedValuesRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.throw_error(SnappyNative.java:84)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.rawUncompress(Native Method)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.rawUncompress(Snappy.java:444)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.uncompress(Snappy.java:480)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readFully(SnappyInputStream.java:135)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.readHeader(SnappyInputStream.java:92)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.<init>(SnappyInputStream.java:58)
    at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.compressedInputStream(CompressionCodec.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.wrapForCompression(BlockManager.scala:1164)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$$anonfun$4.apply(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator$$anonfun$4.apply(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:299)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:53)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: If you have a reliable reproduction for this issue, could you comment at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4105, the Spark JIRA ticket for tracking this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better that you use another compression codec like lz4. To do so in conf/spark-defaults.conf add this a new line: *spark.io.compression.codec    lz4*
to change compression codec from snappy (default) to lz4
However, this problem reported as a bug and has been reopened in the Apache Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4105

Answer (score 0):

Check if you executor also have `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` or high GC pressure? Having no memory might have caused snappy to fail due to not able to acquire memory. In any case, increasing executor memory allocation and specially spark.memory.shuffleFraction should help